# How to prevent a bounce when swapping views with fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

TL;DR:

Container has a view that has height of 10.

> Height == Container(10) + Static(10) == **20**

I then change the view in container, which has a height of 50

1) Add new view to container:

> Height == OldView(10) + NewView(50) + Static(10) == **70**

2) Remove old view from container

> Height == NewView(50) + Static(10) = **60**

So the height goes from **20 -> 70 -> 60**, which produces a bounce.
I want to go directly from 20 -> 60

---

I have a container that swaps divs, depending on the state of a checkbox

Below it are three more static views (In this case, the "Timer Precision" and "Hide Progress" and "Shape" controls)

[image]

[image]

I swap the div in the container with this:

```
function showSurveyIf(isChecked)
{
  if( isChecked ) {
    $("#surveyDeathContainer").fadeIn(100);
    $("#specifyDeathContainer").fadeOut(100);
  } else {
    $("#surveyDeathContainer").fadeOut(100);
    $("#specifyDeathContainer").fadeIn(100);
  }
}
```

But my issue is that this code makes the static views jump.

For example, if you check the checkbox, it will first add the survey questions, which bumps the static views way down, and then makes the date field disappear, which brings the static views back up.

What I would like to have is just move the static views **once**, downwards or upwards depending on which view is coming.

Logically to me, this would mean that I need the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to execute at the same exact time, but I don't think that's possible?

Or is there just another way entirely to do this better?

Comment: can you post a fiddle showing the issue

Comment: Will try to find some time tonight to do so-- though I do hope that my description of the issue should be ample.  Will edit in a tl;dr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was actually with using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, it didn't actually remove/add the divs until the opacity fully transitioned, causing this bounce.

By using `show` and `hide` instead, there isn't a bounce

Answer (score 0):

THE PROBLEM:

jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods actually manipulate the css `display` attribute - that is why the static elements bounce

THE SOLUTION:

```
// make the element invisible - display should still be with 'block' value
$("#specifyDeathContainer").animate({opacity: 0.0001}, 100, function() 
{
    $(this).fadeOut(); // now - make display -> 'none'
    $("#surveyDeathContainer").fadeIn(100); // and make the new element visible with animation
});
```

Comment: what is `this` in this context?

Comment: nvm figured it out ^^  it's `specifyDeathContainer`

Comment: but the issue now is that after turning to opacity to 0 (why did you make it 0.0001?) it needs to be set back to 1?  playing with it now

Comment: and actually it doesn't really resolve the issue at all regarding the height change :\